# Почему не работает exec("global numb")?

Tags: python, рефлексия, exec, global-variables

У меня возник вопрос, как сделать переменную глобальной, не зная заранее её имени. Первое что мне пришло в голову, это использовать **exec()**, но, видимо, я не до конца понял как работает эта функция. Я попробовал:

```
def df(variable):
    exec(f"global {variable}")
    exec(f"{variable} = 1")

numb = 10
variable = "numb"
print(numb)
df(variable)
print(numb)
```

В моих мечтах вывод должен получиться

```
10
1
```

Однако выходит

```
10
10
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите что я делаю не так.
Если **exec()** на такое не способен, то может быть есть другая функция, которая может это сделать.

PS: Если что, то это просто пример, в полном коде переменная variable задаётся путём ввода с клавиатуры, но там это тоже не работает((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мечты сбываются!

```
def df(variable):
    exec(f"global {variable}")
    exec(f"{variable} = 1", globals())

numb = 10
variable = "numb"
print(numb)
df(variable)
print(numb)
```

Как указали в комментариях, `exec(f"global {variable}")` можно не писать.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то `exec(f"global {variable}")` теперь можно не писать

Comment: @Koe-kto да, это так

Comment: не можно не писать, а ненужно писать!

Comment: @Александр почему? и зачем правки "подсветка синтаксиса", если он и так подсвечен?

Comment: так надо, будет подсвечивать именно python

Comment: @Александр я не вижу разницы по превью. Посмотрел ваш последний ответ, там такая же подсветка.

Comment: @Александр стоит ответить перед тем, как делать дальнейшие правки, чтобы мне не пришлось отклонять их и вам не пришлось делать лишнюю работу

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать ваши ответы лучше

Comment: @Александр почему вы решили, что они становятся лучше, когда они выглядят одинаково?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109831/discussion-between--and-).